# Window.Print() Not working in FF3

Tags: javascript, printing

I am trying to print a portion of the page in FF3.  This works fine in IE7.  In FF, the page correctly changes to the part I am trying to print, but the Print Dialog never appears.  Here is my code:

```
function PrintPage() {
    var fullPage = document.body.innerHTML;
    document.body.innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').innerHTML;
    document.focus();
    window.print();
    document.body.innerHTML= fullPage; 
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to show the area that you are wanting to print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.focus` doesn't exist in FF. I suppose your code blows up with a TypeError when calling `document.focus`, right before `window.print`. Does print dialog appear if you remove conflicting statement?